# Calling template in class

Tags: c++, templates

I hope to create a static bool template function that multiple classes may use. I am using this function as a comparator to sort a vector of points. This is what i've done so far:

> class.h

```
class Point2D
{
protected:
        int x;
        int y;
public:
        int getX();
        int getY();
        Point2D();
        Point2D(int x, int y);

        template< typename T>
            T sortAscending(T a, T b )
            {
                return a.getX() < b.getX();
            }


        static bool sortAscending(Point2D a,  Point2D b);

}
```

> Inside main.cpp

```
// my vector contains objects of Point2D that i wish to 
//sort according to the value of x coordinates.

sort(p2Vec.begin(),p2Vec.end(),Point2D::sortAscending);
```

Gives me error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘sort(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator,
>   )’

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `sortAscending` doesn't sort but **compare**.

Comment: Yes i do understand that its comparing. sorry for my weird naming convention..

Comment: What I am saying now does not relate to the question asked, but a piece of advice;
I suggest putting x and y in an array as such:
```cpp
int coord[2 /* X */][2 /* Y */] = {{1,0},{0,1}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax would be:

```
std::sort(p2Vec.begin(), p2Vec.end(), &Point2D::sortAscending<Point2D>);
```

and requires the method to be `static`.

But better create a struct outside:

```
struct LessByGetX
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator () (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
    }
};
```

and use it:

```
std::sort(p2Vec.begin(), p2Vec.end(), LessByGetX{});
```

Alternatively, you might use directly lambda:

```
std::sort(p2Vec.begin(), p2Vec.end(), [](const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! i will give all of them a try now.

Comment: For the first method, I've gotten a `error: could not convert ‘(a.Point2D::getX() < b.Point2D::getX())’ from ‘bool’ to ‘Point2D’`.. Also, for the second method, do i store the struct in my .h file or .cpp file?

Comment: return type has also to be changed to `bool` instead of `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda function here like following :

```
std::sort(p2Vec.begin(),p2Vec.end(),
          [](const Point2D & p1, const Point2D & p2) {
        return Point2D::sortAscending( p1, p2); 
      });
```

See [here](https://rextester.com/YNQ39670)

Comment: Thank you for your help but i just realised that my template function will not work outside Point2D class as you cannot virtual a template function.. I was hoping i could implement this on Point3D where there is x coordinates as well... Nonetheless, thank you for your effort.